# Tables with same name in uppercase and lowercase

Tags: mysql

In MYSQL, is it possible to make a table with same name but with lowercase and uppercase. eg "abc" and "ABC" tables in the same database?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do it, and even if there is. Don't .

Comment: I just want to know if it is allowed by NoSQL or not. if it gives an exception if i make something like this?

Answer (score 0):

MySql:

```
mysql>  create temporary table tt (s varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>  create temporary table TT (s varchar(100));
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'TT' already exists

select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.7.19-log |
+------------+
```

MongoDB:

```
> db.createCollection('tt');
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.createCollection('TT');
{ "ok" : 1 }
> show collections;
TT
tt
> db.version();
3.4.9
```

Is it answer on your question?)

Comment: Is it answer on your question? Did it help you somehow?)

Comment: Yes but this is for mysql wanted to know about nosql

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, this helped a lot.

Comment: Glad to help)))